# NSOutlineView unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift, macos, nsoutlineview

I am trying to make a **file browser** in my app that opens in a side panel (with a split view controller).

The source is a URL brought by a prepareForSegue method in the previous viewController.

**Each time the vc loads i have the fatal error :**

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

The compiler locates the error to where i declare :

> outlineView.delegate = self
>   outlineView.dataSource = self

**I tried :**
 1. Undoing and redoing all my outlets connections, by code, by
    storyboard
 2. Reconnecting delegates and datasource by code, by storyboard
 3. I thought maybe something was wrong in my datasource method and i rewrote it 5 times
 4. I tried to put my setDelegatesAndDatasource method in the viewDidAppear too, thinking it was a problem of view life cycle

I can't understand what's going on.
Thanks for your help.

'''

```
extension ViewControllerSource : NSOutlineViewDataSource, NSOutlineViewDelegate {   

    func setDelegatesAndDatasources(){
        outlineView.delegate = self
        outlineView.dataSource = self
    }


    // MARK: - NSOutlineView Datasource

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: Any?) -> Int {
        if let fileSystemItem = item as? FileSystemItem {
            return fileSystemItem.children.count
        }
        return 1

    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: Any?) -> Any {
        if let fileSystemItem = item as? FileSystemItem {
            return fileSystemItem.children[index]
        }
        return rootfileSystemItem
    }

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: Any) -> Bool {
        if let fileSystemItem = item as? FileSystemItem {
            return fileSystemItem.hasChildren()
        }
        return false
    }

    // MARK: - NSOutlineView Delegate

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) -> NSView? {
        guard let colIdentifier = tableColumn?.identifier else { return nil }

        if colIdentifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "col1") {
            let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "cell1")
            guard let cell = outlineView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView else { return nil }

            if let collection = item as? FileSystemItem {
                cell.textField?.stringValue = collection.name ?? "Title not available"
                cell.textField?.isEditable = false
                cell.textField?.wantsLayer = true
                cell.imageView?.image = collection.icon
                // cell.textField?.delegate = self
            } else {
                cell.textField?.stringValue = "unknown item"
                cell.textField?.isEditable = false
                cell.textField?.wantsLayer = true
            }

            return cell
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }


}
```

'''

And here is the main viewController file :

'''

```
class ViewControllerSource: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var outlineView: NSOutlineView!

    var echo:Echo? {
        didSet {
            echo!.checkFolderIntegrity()
            rootfileSystemItem = FileSystemItem(url: echo!.url)
            let window = self.view.window?.windowController as! WindowControllerEcho
            window.directoryPath.url = echo!.url
        }
    }


    let propertyKeys: [URLResourceKey] = [.localizedNameKey, .effectiveIconKey, .isDirectoryKey, .typeIdentifierKey]
    var rootfileSystemItem: FileSystemItem! {
        didSet {
            displayItems()
            outlineView.reloadData()
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Initialization

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setDelegatesAndDatasources()
    }


    func displayItems(){
        for fileSystemItem in rootfileSystemItem.children as [FileSystemItem] {
            print("item : \(fileSystemItem)")
            for subItem in fileSystemItem.children as [FileSystemItem] {
                print("\(fileSystemItem.name) - \(subItem.name)")
            }
        }
    }
}




extension ViewControllerSource : EchoDelegate {
    func didLoad(echo: Echo) {
        self.echo = echo

    }
}
```

'''

Comment: *Each time the vc loads...* How does it load?

Comment: It is nested in a VerticalSplitViewController in a NSWindowController. The window is called via a segue in storyboard. The prepareForSegue has been overridden in the previous VC to pass the "echo" entity : 

    override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == NSStoryboardSegue.Identifier(stringLiteral: "echoSegue") {
            (segue.destinationController as! WindowControllerEcho).echo = content[tableview.selectedRow]
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prepareForSegue` code reveals the mistake:

You are setting `echo` in `prepareForSegue`. This causes to call the property observer `didSet`. However at this moment the view is not loaded yet and force unwrapping the type crashes.

The solution is to move the code in `didSet` into `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` and delete the property observer. Nevertheless I recommend to optional bind `window`

```
var echo : Echo!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setDelegatesAndDatasources()
    echo.checkFolderIntegrity()
    rootfileSystemItem = FileSystemItem(url: echo.url)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated : Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let window = self.view.window?.windowController as? WindowControllerEcho {
        window.directoryPath.url = echo.url
    }
}
```

Setting `delegate` and `dataSource` once is sufficient. If you are using storyboard or Xib the most convenient way is to connect both in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This solution doesn't work yet but it seems it is related to my prepareForSegue that doesn't work and leaves my "var echo" empty.

Comment: The fatal error now indicates the echo.checkFolderIntegrity().  I tried to follow the way i pass my echo entity through the views and it seems it doesn't make its way... It seems the problem wasn't where i expected it to be :)